# Best way to use Photoshop CS3 in Linux

Tags: linux, photoshop

I don't want to use Mac or Windows at work but I have a lot of work in Photoshop when I have to create an HTML page from a Photoshop design.

What is the best way to use Photoshop CS3 in Linux, Wine, virtualization, ... ???

Comment: How is this programming related?

Answer (score 5):

Wine has been a bit flaky with me before when going with Photoshop (keyboard shortcuts behaved weird) and it doesn't support latest versions.

Using virtualization is working like a charm though, and you can go the easy way with software like VirtualBox. It's easy to use, there's plenty of tutorials on the web, and it's usually in your default repository.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I have Photoshop CS3 working under wine on Gentoo Linux. Installation was flawless and it runs without error. There are some display issues on the toolbar, but nothing unmanageable.

Photoshop CS2 has a [gold rating](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=2631) in the wine app db, so you could use that if you're prepared to sacrifice some of the functionality introduced in the later versions.

Personally, I've found Photoshop 7 is still an acceptable minimum for my work as a web designer.

For a long term solution though, I'd recommend either CS2/wine or a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to say it, but you might just have to suck it up and use Windows or OSX if you want to use Photoshop. As already said, Wine doesn't work with CS3 and after giving Photoshop CS3 a try using VirtualBox from Fedora Core it was a less than enjoyable experience. Then again, if you're on a reasonably powerful machine then it might be okay.

Does your job require the use of Photoshop apart from the need to open PSD files? You could probably get on just fine with the GIMP if needed. Also, I'm sure that OSX will have some other great raster graphics tools.

So there's your choices, go with VirtualBox, go with Windows/OSX or use a Windows box.

Comment: I open the PSD files to get the layers

Comment: You can extract the raw layers fine in Gimp, but it doesn't support some of the newer layer combination options, so the final composited image may look a bit off. +1 for VirtualBox!

Comment: In all honesty, being a Web Designer/Developer, Photoshop is overkill for basic design. If we were dealing with real photo-manipulation or touching up digital art then perhaps it'd be worthwhile to use PS but for the task of opening a PSD something like the GIMP is all that is needed.

Comment: If the layer has layer styles (drop shadow, gradient overlay, etc.), the GIMP will not be able to open it all and the image will be incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine under VirtualBox, but very slow in my opinion, for example with read/write file access. I've got a Intel Core Duo 2 with 2 Gb Memory, SATA2 HD and NVIDIA 8600

I used it in that way for a long but since some time ago I use it through [wine](http://www.winehq.org) and I'm very happy, it runs fast. Of course, through wine it doesn't looks and works exactly as window version but enough for me to work fast with Camera Raw and image processing

Answer (score 0):

Abe,
If you only need image layers from the file, I have a portable command line tool which can extract them to PNGs: http://telegraphics.com.au/sw/#psdparse